# How do I list the number of reviews on my account using the google plus api?

Tags: google-plus

I have spent a lot of time today trying to work out how I can get the number of reviews I have done on google plus.  Ideally I would also love to get a list of the content for the actual reviews too.

Is there any pointers on how I can get that. I have spent ages in the google plus api docs and I am just hitting brick walls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Google+ API endpoint for getting a users own reviews. You can [open a feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/entry) but such an endpoint might be better suited for the Google Maps API.